# Programmatically Change the Output Format of Log4j 2.x

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am using the following code to configure Log4j from the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html).  I would like to change the pattern.  No matter how I edit the `pattern` attribute, the output format stays the same.  How do I change the output format?  I would like to set the `pattern` to `%-5level: %msg%n%throwable`.

```
ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
builder.setConfigurationName("BuilderTest");
builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
.addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));
AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
.addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
.addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));
builder.add(appenderBuilder);
builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", Level.DEBUG)
.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).addAttribute("additivity", false));
builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems working fine. I have following in a test class (your code in instance initialiser):

```
{
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
    builder.setConfigurationName("BuilderTest");
    builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));

    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%d Thread:[%t] %-5level: MSG: %msg%n%throwable"));
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));

    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", Level.DEBUG).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).addAttribute("additivity", false));
    builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
    Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
}
```

Using `Configurator.initialize()` ensures that the newly built Configuration is used as new default config, so created context does not have to be used explicitly when creating the `Logger`.

```
@Test
public void testLogger() throws Exception {
    Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("loggerName");
    log.error("Error");
    log.warn("Warning");
    log.debug("Debug");
    log.info("Info");
}
```

And the above results in (please notice modified pattern):

```
2017-03-14 16:29:03,188 Thread:[main] ERROR: MSG:Error
2017-03-14 16:29:03,190 Thread:[main] WARN : MSG:Warning
2017-03-14 16:29:03,190 Thread:[main] DEBUG: MSG:Debug
2017-03-14 16:29:03,190 Thread:[main] INFO : MSG:Info
```

---

**EDIT :**Initial explicit use of `LoggerContext.getLogger()` is not necessary, and regular `LogManager.getLogger()` ensures that the custom configuration is being used when creating loggers.

Comment: I didn't realize I had to use the context. How do I make the created context as the default context for all loggers?

Comment: You don't. I thought you did, but using `LogManager` works as well. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I must be doing something else weird because I can't seem to get the date and time to disappear.

Comment: This is my log format pattern: "%-5level: %msg%n%throwable"